# Xamarin XAML file wont change after changing some code

Tags: xaml, xamarin

In my XAML File after changing some code inside it and then debug on my phone, the changes I made do not reflect on my phone. It keep showing my old code.

Old code :

```
<ListView
       ItemsSource="{Binding Allgroups}"
       RowHeight="75"
       IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Label Text="{Binding NameNative}"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding TitleWithItemCount}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

new code :

```
 <Label Text="HELOO WORLD  "></Label>
```

I Noticed every time i run the code , it keep showing the list.I have to click the save button then the list disappear and hello world appear .

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet from both the old and new code where you are observing the lack of expected change?

Comment: @Josiah I added some code

Comment: You aren't editing a `tmp` view are you? If you hover over the view's tab, it hasn't got `tmp` in the path does it?

Comment: @JamesS no it does not have temp in it

Comment: the problem came again

Answer (score 0):

I reset VS settings and relaunched it .
worked for me

```
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categoriesxx}" IsGrouped="True">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"></GridItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label Text="{Binding NameNative}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title"></Label>
                        <Button Image="{Binding StateIcon}"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                BorderColor="Transparent"
                                BorderWidth="0"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ExpandCommand ,Source={x:Reference ServiceListPage}}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I problem reoccurred. resetting and relaunching did not fix it this time .

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT this is the XAML code i have problem with . apparently this code specificly cause the problem . because when i remove it and put only a label it works fine .

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I changed the code from using List to ObservableCollection , and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my grouping class and everything worked . apparently its a code problem not a debugger problem .